# Meteor run code on refresh, not render

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactive-programming

I have read many answers on this site already, but this one keeps me scratching my head:

I am using an ace editor (mizzao/meteor-sharejs) on a meteor page. I simply want to update it's content reactively. This is should be done through the method ace.edit("editor").setValue("foo");

Now, I can't get it to work.
Why:
 1. OnRender is not an option, because that only runs when it is first
    rendered / not updated
 2. I cannot use a helper, because the editor itself is entered through handlebars, and therefore 'cannot be found' before the update finishes.
({{> sharejsAce docid=docid onRender=config id="editor"}})

So the question: Is there a way to run code like this *after* a reactive update, or is there another way I can realize my requirement?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How about `Tracker.afterFlush`?

According to http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_afterflush:

> Schedules a function to be called during the next flush, or later in the current flush if one is in progress, after all invalidated computations have been rerun. The function will be run once and not on subsequent flushes unless afterFlush is called again.

Comment: Thanks, that might be it. However, I want the method to be executed only for a certain template. Right now, it is being executed after _every_ flush
Tracker.afterFlush(function(){
 ace.edit("editor").setValue(this.data.skeleton);
});

Comment: No, no after *every* flush - `Tracker.afterFlush` calls the callback only once per call.

Comment: but can I get it to only run the callback code when a certain template is updated / flushed? (or check inside the callback function what template was updated?)

Comment: How about creating autorun in `onRender` of editor? It would be called reactively and you've got access to editor itself there.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is still not it. The method doesn't get called when the reactive data on the page changes. 
Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but it gets triggered only onrendered...

Thanks for your efforts though.

Anybody else has a suggestion? how to call a method after reactive data changes?

Comment: Maybe I'm explaining it in the wrong way. It is not the case that the actual collection data changes, just that the template stays on screen (not re-rendered) but the handlebars content is changed because we are changing the current collection to be viewed within the template. So, the original item doesn't change, we are just seeing another item in the same template. I would like to call the update ace method at that time...